# How can I recursively display an XML listing as a previous ASP:MENU did?

Tags: javascript, html, css, recursion, menu

I am trying to convert a previous asp:menu item to javascript.  This is the javascript code I have written:

```
    function GetMainMenu() {
        var html = '';
        var finalHTML = '';
        finalHTML += '<div class="dropdown" style="width:100%">';
        finalHTML += '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">';
        finalHTML += '<li class="dropdown">';
        finalHTML += '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" style="height:18px;color:#003366">';
        finalHTML += 'Main Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>';

        var MainMenu = null;
        MainMenu = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        MainMenu = readXml("/public/FHSMenu.xml");


        finalHTML += buildList(MainMenu.getElementsByTagName("Menu"));


        finalHTML += '</li>';
        finalHTML += '</ul>';
        finalHTML += '</div>';

        alert(finalHTML);
        document.getElementById("preMainMenu").innerHTML = finalHTML;

        var x = null;
        x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        var item;


        function buildList(data) {
            html += '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';

            x = data;

            for (item = 0; item < x.length ; item++) {

                var y = x[item].getElementsByTagName("Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                var u = null;
                try {
                    u = x[item].getElementsByTagName("URL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                } catch (e) {
                    u = '';
                }

                if (u != '') {
                    html += '<li><a href="' + u + '" style="font-size:12px;color:#003366" >' + y + '</a></li>';
                } else {
                    html += '<li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu" >';
                    html += '<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="font-size:12px;color:#003366" >' + y + '</a>';
                    html += '</li>';
                    //var SubMenu = x[item].getElementsByTagName("Menu");
                    //if (SubMenu != undefined && SubMenu.length > 0) {
                    //    html += buildList(SubMenu); // Submenu found. Calling recursively same method (and wrapping it in a div)
                    //}
                }

            }

            html += '</ul>';
            return html;
        }

    }
```

The XML file was written for use with ASP:MENU and is still being used with legacy web applications so I need a way to recursively display the menus in a dropdown method so the user will still see essentially the same drop down menu with sub menus.   So far I am having trouble getting the initial root menus displayed and then calling the same routine to get any submenus from the root menu (if that makes any sense.)  Currently the alert is displaying ALL the items that have "Menu" in the tag and not just the few root items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> <LeftNavMenu>   <Menu>
    <MenuId>63</MenuId>
    <Title>Clinical Care</Title>
    <URL />
    <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
    <Menu>
      <MenuId>1660</MenuId>
      <ParentId>63</ParentId>
      <Title>Ambulatory EHR</Title>
      <URL>some_link</URL>
      <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
      <MenuId>3649</MenuId>
      <ParentId>63</ParentId>
      <Title>Angel Eye</Title>
      <URL>some_link</URL>
      <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
      <MenuId>1610</MenuId>
      <ParentId>63</ParentId>
      <Title>Clarity</Title>
      <URL>some_link</URL>
      <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
    </Menu>   </Menu>   <Menu>
    <MenuId>3</MenuId>
    <Title>Corporate</Title>
    <URL />
    <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
    <Menu>
      <MenuId>1487</MenuId>
      <ParentId>3</ParentId>
      <Title>Become an Organ Donor</Title>
      <URL>some_link</URL>
      <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
      <MenuId>1845</MenuId>
      <ParentId>3</ParentId>
      <Title>Brand Style Guide</Title>
      <URL>some_link</URL>
      <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
      <MenuId>2153</MenuId>
      <ParentId>3</ParentId>
      <Title>Calendars</Title>
      <URL />
      <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
      <Menu>
        <MenuId>2155</MenuId>
        <ParentId>2153</ParentId>
        <Title>Freemanhealth.com Events</Title>
        <URL>some_link</URL>
        <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
      </Menu>
      <Menu>
        <MenuId>2391</MenuId>
        <ParentId>2153</ParentId>
        <Title>Kronos Calendar</Title>
        <URL>some_link</URL>
        <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
      </Menu>
      <Menu>
        <MenuId>2158</MenuId>
        <ParentId>2153</ParentId>
        <Title>Payroll</Title>
        <URL>some_link</URL>
        <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
      </Menu>
      <Menu>
        <MenuId>2156</MenuId>
        <ParentId>2153</ParentId>
        <Title>Professional Development</Title>
        <URL>some_link</URL>
        <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
      </Menu>
      <Menu>
        <MenuId>2157</MenuId>
        <ParentId>2153</ParentId>
        <Title>Room Scheduling</Title>
        <URL>some_link</URL>
        <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
      </Menu>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
      <MenuId>8</MenuId>
      <ParentId>3</ParentId>
      <Title>Car Pool</Title>
      <URL>some_link</URL>
      <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
      <MenuId>1280</MenuId>
      <ParentId>3</ParentId>
      <Title>CMN (Children's Miracle Network)</Title>
      <URL>some_link</URL>
      <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
      <MenuId>181</MenuId>
      <ParentId>3</ParentId>
      <Title>Employee Handbook</Title>
      <URL>some_link</URL>
      <ZOrder>0</ZOrder>
    </Menu>   </Menu> </LeftNavMenu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally cobbled together the method to recursively load the XML Menu file and though since I didn't get a response and this might be useful to someone else trying to convert an asp:menu to javascript I wanted to show how it was accomplished.  Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function readXml(xmlFile) {
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);
        var tagObj = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Menu");
        var menuidValue = tagObj[0].getElementsByTagName("MenuId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        try {
            var parentidValue = tagObj[0].getElementsByTagName("Parentid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        } catch (err) {
            var parentidValue = 0;
        }
        var titleValue = tagObj[0].getElementsByTagName("Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        try {
            var urlValue = tagObj[0].getElementsByTagName("URL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        } catch (err) {
            var urlValue = '';
        }

        var zorderValue = tagObj[0].getElementsByTagName("ZOrder")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        return xmlDoc
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetMainMenu();
    });


    function buildList(data) {

        var item;
        var html = '';

        html += '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';

        for (item = 0; item < data.length ; item++) {

            var Title = data[item].getElementsByTagName("Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            var URL = null;
            try {
                URL = data[item].getElementsByTagName("URL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            } catch (e) {
                URL = '';
            }

            if (URL == '') {
                html += '<li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu" >';
                html += '<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="font-size:12px;color:#003366" >' + Title + '</a>';
                html += buildList(data[item].getElementsByTagName("Menu")); // Submenu found. Calling recursively same method
                html += '</li>';
            } else {
                html += '<li><a href="' + URL + '" style="font-size:12px;color:#003366" >' + Title + '</a></li>';
            }
        }

        html += '</ul>';
        return html;
    }


    function GetMainMenu() {
        var html = '';
        var finalHTML = '';
        finalHTML += '<div class="dropdown" style="width:100%">';
        finalHTML += '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">';
        finalHTML += '<li class="dropdown">';
        finalHTML += '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" style="height:18px;color:#003366">';
        finalHTML += 'Main Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>';

        var MainMenu = null;
        MainMenu = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        MainMenu = readXml("/public/FHSMenu.xml");

        finalHTML += buildList(MainMenu.childNodes[1].childNodes,html);


        finalHTML += '</li>';
        finalHTML += '</ul>';
        finalHTML += '</div>';

        document.getElementById("preMainMenu").innerHTML = finalHTML;

    }

</script>
```